# incompatible pointer types in C || void (*)(void *)

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I have two functions, and the console say that the pointers is incompatible
`void printList(tList, void(void*))`
The function i'm passing is
`void printUser(tUser*);`
`printList(user->friends, printUser);`
Can anyone help me ? i dont understand what wrong in that.

Comment: What are trying to do? Question unclear.

Comment: I'm trying to pass a function (void (*)(tUser)) as a parameter, but the console is saying that is incompatible. ps: parameter expected = void (void*) | parameter given = void (tUser*)

Comment: What don't you understand? The function's argument type is `tUser*`, but `printList` exxpects a function whose argument is `void*`.

Comment: But why is wrong passing a tUser* as a void* ?

Comment: A little bit of more context would be nice, but I guess this is one of these cases where you can't get around using casting.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function that takes a `void *` as an argument, not a `tUser *` as an argument.  Change your `void printUser(tUser*)` to `void printUser(void*)`, and then within the definition of `printUser`, you can cast the argument to the type it needs to be:

```
void printUser(void *arg) {
    tUser *casted_arg = (tUser *)arg;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Make sense to me !! Thanks